# Prepare data for inserting ST_GeomFromText in database (Codeigniter + MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a problem inserting my data in database with Codeigniter. I have this testing seed function

```
$latitude = rand(45.500000 * 1000000, 46.400000 * 1000000) / 1000000;
$longitude = rand(13.600000 * 1000000, 15.500000 * 1000000) / 1000000;
$data = array(
    'unique_id' => '12319334',
    'latitude' => $latitude,
    'longitude' => $longitude,
    'coordinates' => "ST_GeomFromText('POINT($latitude $longitude)')",
);
$locationId = $this->Locations->insert($data);
```

And this is insert function in model

```
function insert($data, $tableName = "")
    {
        if ($tableName == "") {
            $tableName = $this->table;
        }
        $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

And this is a query that happens

```
INSERT
INTO
  `locations`(
    `unique_id`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`,
    `coordinates`
  )
VALUES(
  'ZTE1NGY2YT',
  45.990292,
  14.948462,
  'ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT(45.582315 14.821478)\')'
)
```

Error i get is `Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`

After some testing in phpmyadmin i figure out that query for inserting this kind of data should look like this

```
INSERT
INTO
  `locations`(
    `unique_id`,
    `latitude`,
    `longitude`,
    `coordinates`
  )
VALUES(
  'ZTE1NGY2YT',
  45.990292,
  14.948462,
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(45.582315 14.821478)')
)
```

So somehow i need to get rid off single quotes (') in `'ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT(45.582315 14.821478)\')'` line

Anybody got idea how to properly prepare data (without executing direct query, since there is a lot more data to store) so it can be process properly?

If you need any additional information please let me know and i will provide.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this did it

```
$this->db->set('coordinates', "ST_GeomFromText('POINT($latitude $longitude)')", false);
```

So i made a small hack on my model (i know its not pretty but it works for now) and data is inserted..

```
function insert($data, $tableName = "")
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'coordinates') {
                $this->db->set('coordinates', $value, false);
                unset($data['coordinates']);
            }
        }
        if ($tableName == "") {
            $tableName = $this->table;
        }
        $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Comment: Might be better to do: `if (isset($data['coordinates'])) { $this->db->set('coordinates', $data['coordinates'], false); unset($data['coordinates']);}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CodeIgniter's database escape logic assumes that the pattern is `field_name => rendered data`. This means that you can't use things like `NOW()` or `MD5()`, or `ST_GeomFromText`. [You can see the logic here:](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/c7c0bdf4f7af7c4e71b073ee87ddb792087bdfac/system/database/DB_driver.php)

```
    foreach ($data as $key => $val)
    {
        $fields[] = $this->escape_identifiers($key);
        $values[] = $this->escape($val);
    }
```

The best option I've managed is to [extend the DB driver](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers) and have the model call a custom function. The other option is to drop back into raw SQL and manually escape the values.

Comment: i made it with $this->db->set
check my answer